# Commit changes in xfce4-settings-manager?

Tags: configuration, xfce, display-settings

In xfce4 I can run `xfce4-settings-manager` which opens a *registry* of values I can set (which otherwise would be set via a GUI). I thought both forms to modify the settings should be equivalent. However if set the value such as to activate a monitor/display, I can observe that the setting is not actually enabled (even though the checkbox Next to `Active Boolean` has been set).

[image: xfce4-setting-manager]

This begs the question: *How can I commit those settings made?*

Bonus: Where do those settings get stored and can I set them without the xfce4-settings-manager (i.e. via writing to a file, or calling a command line tool? I assume `xfconf-query` is the right tool?)

**Update**
Using the command line

```
xfconf-query -c displays -p /Default/eDP-1/Active -s true
```

I am able to modify the value (and it also shows the modification in the "Settings Editor" window of `xfce4-settings-manager`) but the effect is yet not enabled. In a nutshell neither `xfconf-query` nor `xfce4-settings-manager` seem to commit (as in "bring to effect") the change.

** Further investigation **

It seems that some other settings such as the mouse input device to indeed get set via `xfconf-query` and the `xfce4-settins-manager`. For example this
line:

```
xfconf-query -c pointers -p /DELL08E100_06CBCD97_Touchpad/Properties/Device_Enabled -s 0
```

does indeed disable the touchpad.
It seems for the moment that the settins get sometimes *commited* and sometimes not. What is going on?

Comment: According to [Configuration Storage System - xfconf](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfconf/start), "Xfconf stores all its data in XML files", although it unfortunately doesn't indicate the location of those files.

Comment: With the displays you want to use enabled in the Settings Editor, can they be configured through the [Display](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/display) configuration dialog? If necessary, that dialog can be opened from a terminal with the command `xfce4-display-settings`.

Comment: @David I want the setting to be the result of a script, hence I need to automize it and the GUI will not allow for that. I know how to do it manually using the mouse [#ratpoison](https://nongnu.org/ratpoison/) ;)

Answer (score 1):

`--replace` option of XSettings daemon for Xfce replaces xsettings daemon (if any is currently running)

```
xfsettingsd --replace
```

More can be read about **xfsettingsd** at `man xfsettingsd`.

Comment: Will this command save any settings change (keybinds, etc.)  to the configutration files as well? I am looking for some way to avoid having to logout just for making my changes persistent.

Answer (score 1):

After making your changes, you can apply the display profile by tickling the `/Schemes/Apply` property.

You can either apply the Default profile or a custom profile.

Apply the default profile:

```
$ xfconf-query --create -c displays -p /Schemes/Apply -t string -s Default
```

Apply a custom profile:

```
$ xfconf-query --create -c displays -p /Schemes/Apply -t string -s 89e4fa7c6e21bf128815cf184349592868a477ce
```

In my case, I saved a custom profile called "Dual" using the Advanced -> Profiles section of `xfce4-display-settings`, then determined the profile identifier with:

```
$ xfconf-query -c displays --list -v | grep Dual
/89e4fa7c6e21bf128815cf184349592868a477ce                            Dual
```